# How to use custom font in jsPDF to create pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jspdf

I'm trying to create a simple pdf doc using javascript. I found jsPDF but I don't figure out how to use "CALIBRI" font text. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you rendered it on a browser as calibri?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaletly I don't think that is possible. The documentation states that you can use `getFontList()` to see what fonts are available. As you can see below it returns `courier`, `times` and `helvetica`.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var elem = document.getElementById('fonts');
elem.innerText = Object.keys(doc.getFontList()).join(', ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fonts"></ul>
```

The capitalized versions of the fonts returned seem to be only for ease of use and are the same as the none-capitalized fonts.